# tracked_vehicle_simple.sdf vehicle not moving?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was trying to run the simulation with [tracked_vehicle_simple.sdf](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/tracked_vehicle_simple.sdf). Whenever I press the keyboard button, it seems that the speeds and the vehicle pose are updated (from checking the topic `/model/simple_tracked/odometry`). However, the vehicle itself is not moving. I wonder if I made any mistake?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29271/tracked_vehicle_simple.sdf-vehicle-not-moving?/) by [nmw](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182112/nmw/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1662).

---

Originally posted by [jrtg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/156210/jrtg/) with karma: 31 on 2023-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0